# Output a boolean from an Rscript into a Bash variable

Tags: r, bash

I have an R script that outputs TRUE or FALSE.  In R, it's using a bona fide T/F data type, but when I echo its return value to bash, it seems to be a string, saying:

`"[1] TRUE"`

or

`"[1] FALSE"`

They are both preceded by [1].  Neither is [0], that is not a typo.  Anyway, the result of this is what when I try to test on the output of this Rscript to run a subsequent script, I have to do string comparison to "[1] TRUE" as below, instead of comparing to "TRUE" or "1" which feels cleaner and better.

```
A=$(Rscript ~/MyR.r)
echo $A
if [ "$A" == "[1] TRUE" ]; then
    bash SecondScript.sh
fi
```

How can I make R either output a true Boolean, or Bash accept the output string and convert it to 0/1 for comparison?  That is, I'd rather test for...

```
if [ $A == TRUE ];
```

than

```
if [ "$A" == "[1] TRUE" ];
```

Is that possible, or should I be happy with this, how it is, which works?

*** UPDATE ***

Here's the minimalized version of the Rscript that generates this...

```
myinput <- TRUE #or FALSE

FunctionName <- function(test){
  if (test == TRUE){
    val <- TRUE
  } else {
    val <- FALSE
  }
  return(val)
}

FunctionName(myinput)
```

Comment: FYI, the [1] is telling you this is the first element of a vector. If you print a vector that has more than one element in it such that the printout extends over more than one row, R helpfully will print [11], [21], [31] etc so you know (for example) its printed 10 values per row. If you print a matrix it labels the rows and columns as [,1] and [1,] for you.

Comment: In addition to the good solutions given below, I believe you can use q(status = val) in the Rscript to say what value is returned to the shell from Rscript. Be careful about this though if you're working with collaborators -- the return value is often used to encode error messages so they might take a non-zero return value as something worth worrying about rather than just a run of the mill answer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Instead of using either print() or the implicit print()-ing that occurs when an object name is offered to the R interpreter, you should be using `cat()` which will not prepend the "[1] " in front of either TRUE or FALSE. If you want 0/1, then use `cat(as.numeric(.))`. Try this instead:

```
myinput <- TRUE #or FALSE
FunctionName <- function(test){
   if (test == TRUE){
              val <- TRUE
                    } else {
              val <- FALSE
            }
   cat(as.numeric(val))
}
FunctionName(myinput)
```

If you needed that value for further processing you could also use this:

```
cat(as.numeric(val)); invisible(val)
```

Comment: This worked perfectly.  Thanks for introducing me to invisible(), too.

Answer (score 1):

You can also define a function in bash that converts the R output into TRUE/FALSE:

```
r_to_bash() {
  echo "$1" | cut -d' ' -f2
}
```

Now you can use it like:

```
A=$(r_to_bash "$A")
if [ $A == TRUE ];
```

Comment: Or `r_to_bash() { echo "${1#* }"; }`

Answer (score 1):

You could also change the last line of the script to:

```
write( FunctionName( myinput ), stdout())
```

This will print just the `TRUE` without the [1].

Answer (score 0):

Short of changing what your R script does, you can do either of the following on the Bash side:

```
if [[ $A == *TRUE* ]]
```

or

```
if [[ $A =~ TRUE ]]
```

In the second case, with regex matching, it's normally recommended that the pattern be put in a variable:

```
pattern=TRUE
if [[ $A =~ $pattern ]]
```

but in obviously simple cases such as this it's not necessary.