# Shell script: Pass objects from inside Rscript to the shell script

Tags: r, linux, bash, shell, rscript

I have a shell script file which has an Rscript file in it and some other hadoop commands.
For eg: some R script(get_Data) like this:

```
data<-data.frame(replicate(10,sample(0:1,1000,rep=TRUE)))
dimensions<-dim(data)
sum<-sum(X1)
write.table(data,file="test.csv")
```

And some shell script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
Rscript get_Data.r
wait
hadoop fs -put test.csv /user
wait
hive -e"load data inpath '/user/test.csv' into db.test;"
if [$? -ne 0]
  then echo "Dimensions: ${dimensions} with sum= ${sum}"
else
echo "Query failed"
```

What I want to do is to use the variables like **dimensions** and **sum** from the rscript and use it in shell script.
How can this be possible?
Any help will be appreciated.

UPDATE:
cat function in R can be used for this, For eg:the following R script (test_r.r)

```
String1<-"This is one"
cat(String1)
```

When the above rscript is used in shell script for eg:

```
#!/bin/bash
v1=${Rscript test_r.r}
echo $v1
```

I get the Output in this case, but I am not able to include multiple variables by doing this

Comment: Does this answer help?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10575005/output-a-boolean-from-an-rscript-into-a-bash-variable

Comment: I tried this approach using the cat method, but one drawback is that I am able to get only one variable. Is there any way in which we can return multiple variables (about 3)

Comment: I would imagine that your receiving application would need to do the parsing.